# A word describing the substance in the human eye

Tags: single-word-requests

How do they call in English that yellowish substance that is sometimes gathered in the corner of a human eye during the sleep?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've got some great answers with the technical term for the substance. However, practically, I've never heard anyone refer to it as anything other than ***sleep***. For example, "He sat up in bed and rubbed the sleep from his eyes."

> **[sleep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleep)**
>   noun
>
> 4. crusty matter present in the corner of an eye upon awakening

It's not the technical term, but if you actually call it "rheum" or "gound", no one's going to have any idea what you're talking about. Depending on how you intend to use the word, I thought that knowledge might help :)

Comment: I never heard one in real life except "eye gook" (rhymes with "hook") but I'm given to understand that this is a term with high regional variation.

Answer (score 6):

It is **rheum**, a mucous discharge from the eye. The [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheum) gives a number of other words, including **eye crust** and **eye gunk**.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Belfast, we called it 'duck's meat'

Comment: Hello, Jim and welcome to ELU. This is a fascinating answer. Can you find an example on the internet say showing that it was quite a widespread usage? And have you any idea _why_ 'duck's meat' rather than say 'sheep's fat'?

Comment: I suspect it is because "meat" = food and it looks like breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

As a euphemism, you could say that one had *a visit from the [Sandman](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sandman)*.  I've heard that expression used on occasion to describe the presence of that yellowish, sand-like grit.

**[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandman)** has an article about this, if you want to read more about it.

Comment: The word **grit** reminds of **gravel**:)